# Masonry crash when i run my project

Tags: ios, crash, autolayout, masonry

that is my code:

```
    UITableView *marketTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
    marketTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:41.0/255.0 green:41.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    marketTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
    marketTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    marketTableView.delegate = self;
    marketTableView.dataSource = self;

    [self.view addSubview:marketTableView];
    [marketTableView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.top.mas_equalTo(self.view.mas_height).offset(64);
        make.bottom.mas_equalTo(self.view.mas_bottom);
        make.left.mas_equalTo(self.view.mas_left);
        make.right.mas_equalTo(self.view.mas_right);
    }];
```

When i run my project it crashes. The lldb info is :

```
-[UITableView mas_makeConstraints:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1ba4c00
```

Why does this happen?
I have installed the [Masonry](https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry) by cocoapods.

Comment: Did you import masonry header?

Comment: yes,i import masonry header